# How can I calculate the difference between two times in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question.
In JavaScript, how can I calculate the difference between two times.

Below I'm getting time values from input form(input type=time) and trying to calculate the difference in between the two times.

```
<scirpt>
   function cal(obj) {
   var time = document.getElementById(obj.id).value;
   document.getElementById("endtime").value = time;
}
</script>
```

in body tag

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="screentime">
    <tr>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item1">
        <td><input type="time" class="starttime" name="starttime" id="starttime" style="height:25px;"/></td>
        <td><input type="time" class="endtime" name="endtime" id="endtime" style="height:25px;" id="disabledInput" disabled/></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="delete" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="javascript:delTime(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item2">
        <td><input type="time" class="starttime" name="starttime" id="starttime" style="height:25px;"/></td>
        <td><input type="time" class="endtime" name="endtime" id="endtime" style="height:25px;"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="delete" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="javascript:delTime(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

in addition, when I clicked a button, 'tr' tags will add and remove from jQuery.
How I select correct tag for calculate.

```
function addTime() {
    var lastItemNo = $("#screentime tr:last").attr("class").replace("item", "");

    var newitem = $("#screentime tr:eq(1)").clone();
    newitem.removeClass();
    newitem.find("td:eq(0)").attr("rowspan", "1");
    newitem.addClass("item"+(parseInt(lastItemNo)+1));

    $("#screentime").append(newitem);
    return;
```

}

Comment: DOM element ID should be **unique**. You have many items with the same IDs.

Comment: Moreover, you shouldn't store IDs in a class name and parse it this way. This fiddle may helpful, a little: http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/8hguqdxn/

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle I made here: https://jsfiddle.net/rjnwhyw7/1/

It is a simple function that essentially just retrieves the values from the input, takes the correct substring representing the hours and minutes and calculates the difference from their integer values. The HTML5 time input also converts PM values to 24-hour time so you don't need to worry about that edge case.

```
function calculate () {
    // Get the string values of each time.
    var startTime = $('.item1 .starttime').val();
    var endTime = $('.item1 .endtime').val();

    // Calculate the difference between hours and minutes by retrieving the correct substring and converting the string value to an integer.
    var hours = parseInt(endTime.substr(0, 2), 10) - parseInt(startTime.substr(0, 2), 10);
    var minutes = parseInt(endTime.substr(3, 5)) - parseInt(startTime.substr(3, 5), 10);
    // Convert the difference to minutes and return it.
    return (hours * 60) + minutes;
}
```

It's up to you regarding how you design the final output and handle negative values. The output can be represented as a string or a value in minutes as I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this code please include any jquery min js
var date1 = new Date('2015-12-11 10:04:07');
 var date2 = new Date('2015-12-11 12:06:05');

var seconds =  (date2- date1)/1000;
var differance = (date2 - date1);

var minutes = (differance - seconds)/ 60;
var hours = (differance - minutes) / 60;

more detail please check this link http://www.allwebdevhelp.com/javascript/js-help-tutorials.php?i=55157